# eval objects property

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have the following two objects

```
public partial class ProgramObj
{
  public int id;
  public PersonObj myPerson;
}

public class PersonObj
{
   public int id;
   public string full_name;
}
```

I am assigning a list of ProgramObj's to a repeater from a SqlDataReader

```
program_list.DataSource = reader;
program_list.DataBind();
```

What I want to do, is access the full_name property of the PersonObj in each ProgramObj
I've tried multiple things, the only thing that gets me an output value is

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "id") %>
```

which gets me the id of the ProgramObj, but I would like to get the name of the PersonObj, I thought

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "myPerson.full_name") %>
```

would work, but it doesn't appear to get me anywhere.

I also tried an ItemDataBound with

```
PersonObj myPerson = (PersonObj)e.Item.DataItem;
lblUserName.Text = myPerson.Full_Name_RFL;
```

and

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "myPerson") %>
```

but i get an error that it cannot cast an object of type DataRecordInternal to PersonObj. thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ItemDataBound should work if you do this:

```
PersonObj myPerson = ((ProgramObj)e.Item.DataItem).myPerson;
lblUserName.Text = myPerson.full_name;
```

Becausse the repeater is bound to a list of ProgramObj object the DataItem will be the ProgramObj. so you then need to get the myPerson property if you want the PersonObj object.

Answer (score 1):

See the [What's the deal with Databinder.Eval and Container.DataItem?](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2004/07/20/what-s-the-deal-with-databinder-eval-and-container-dataitem.aspx) article on asp.net. Also, see this [GridView bound with with Properties of nested class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130351/gridview-bound-with-with-properties-of-nested-class) question on here.