# Could not find a property named 'xxx.yyy' in FormView (two-way binding for nested properties)

Tags: c#, asp.net, objectdatasource, formview

I have this error when I try to update a FormView

> Could not find a property named 'MainContact.FirstName' on the type
>   specified by the DataObjectTypeName property in ObjectDataSource
>   'odsForm'.

I think it is because I use in the EditTemplate a Textbox like this

```
<asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("MainContact.FirstName") %>' ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" />
```

It shows the right text in the Textbox, but apparently it doesn't work when it updates.

This is the datasource of the FormView

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsForm" runat="server" DataObjectTypeName="Helpers.BusinessObjects.EntryItem"
    SelectMethod="GetEntryByEmail" TypeName="Helpers.DataAccessers.EntryHelper"
    UpdateMethod="UpdateEntry">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter SessionField="email" Name="email" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

This is the EntryItem Class

```
 public class EntryItem
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public Person MainContact { get; set; } 
        ...
    }
```

And the Person Class

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

The debugger gets in the FormView `ItemUpdating` event handler, but never in `Helpers.DataAccessers.EntryHelper.UpdateEntry`.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4):

You could write your own control able to perform binding as you want, to be used this way (I made one of this):

```
    <ItemTemplate>
      <%# Eval("MainContact.FirstName")%>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
      <xx:BinderHelper runat="server" DataSource='<%# Bind("MainContact") %>'>
        <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>' ID="txtFirstName" 
             runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
      </xx:BinderHelper>
    </EditItemTemplate>
```

Anyway, I suggest you not to use domain objects directly in pages, and overall **not to write them with an ObjectDataSource**. The problem is that when you will change your domain for example to add a field:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    // just added
    public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
}
```

Then you will need to change all the GridViews, FormViews, etc. to store the BirthDate, otherwise the framework will call your ObjectDataSource Update method putting `null` in the BirthDate. For example:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" DataSourceID="odsForm" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
      <asp:CommandField runat="server" ShowEditButton="True" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" />
 </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>
```

It will read your persons from the database. Each person will have a birth date set. When you save, the person will updated with BirthDate to `null`, because the GridView does not store the new field.

I think the best solution is to write DTOs for databinding (and leave them in the Presentation Layer) and DataObjects. In your case:

```
public class EntryItemView
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string MainContactFirstName { get; set; } 
}

[DataObject]
public class EntryItemViewDataObject {
   [DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select)]
   public EntryItemView GetItem(...) {
       // TODO: read from the database, convert to DTO
   }

   [DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Update)]
   public void Update( EntryItemView entry) {

      EntryItem domainObject = getById(entry.Id);
      // TODO: use EmitMapper or AutoMapper
      domainObject.MainContact.FirstName = entry.MainContactFirstName;

      // TODO: save
   }
}
```

In this way any addition to your domain will be safe for your views, and DataObjects will read/write only the fields they need.

Comment: +1 : I always get burned wasting my time with the `ObjectDataSource` I just hope next time I remember not to bother with them.

Answer (score 1):

Two possible approaches.

First, you could drop `DataObjectTypeName="Helpers.BusinessObjects.EntryItem"` from the definition of your `ObjectDataSource`. I've NEVER used that and bindings always work.

But this will probably not help, as the `Bind/Eval` is probably not able to follow references (`Bind("MainContact.FirstName")`).

Instead, rewrite this as

```
<%# ((EntryItem)Container.DataItem).MainContract.FirstName #>
```

The downside is that you loose automatic two-way binding so you have to help the binder a little. Just add a `Inserting/Updating` handlers to your ObjectDataSource and inside handlers:

```
protected void TheObjectDataSource_Updating( object sender, BlahBlahEventArgs e )
{
    // find the control in the data bound parent
    TextBox txt = (TextBox)YourFormView.FindControl( "txtFirstName" );

    // read the value and add it to parameters
    e.Parameters.Add( "nameofyourparameter", txt.Text );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to a couple sources, it is actually not possible to do two-way binding with nested properties.

Here's one answer to a similar question here on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1195119/370671.

Also, [there's a blog post](http://mikeoff.blogspot.ca/2006/07/using-bind-with-nested-properties.html) describing the issue:

> Now, still in most cases using `ObjectDataSource` will not cause you any problems when what [you] bind is a simple property such as a name of a client i.e.: you have a collection of clients that you bind to a `GridView` and one of the columns displays the name of the client. To do so you use something like `Bind("Name")`. The problem arises when you need to bind to a subproperty such as in
>   `Bind("Address.StreetName")`. This won't work