# List does not show up in binding source

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have the following collection in my database:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Medication> Medications { get; set; }
}

public class Medication
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

However when I bind the Customer data source to my datagridview, I can not get the list of medications, what can I do to get that list?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24430034/how-to-bind-list-inside-list-inside-grid-view

Comment: Show your code which fetches records from the database. I think you need to use `Include` method

Comment: May be you should turn on LazyLoading: `public Icollection<Medication> Medications { get; set; }`?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably achieve this by doing:

```
 List<Medication> medications = new List<Medication>();
        var source = new BindingSource();
        source.DataSource = Medications;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = source;
```

Please try it and tell me if it works.

EDIT: I used this in a program I made:

```
//My list
List<UA> listagem = new List<UA>();
//My class
public class UA
    {
        public string DistritoCod { get; set; }
        public string Distrito { get; set; }
        public UA() { }
    }

//Then this to tell where I wanted the values to go
   UA ua = new UA { };
            ua.DistritoCod = row.Cell(1).GetString();
            ua.Distrito = row.Cell(2).GetString();

listagem.Add(ua);

datagridview1.datasource = listagem;
```

But I was getting my values from a xlsm file, maybe you can addapt your code to this and make it work. But I think this can be a way fo you to move forward.

Comment: source.DataSource = Medications; it says Medications is a type which is not valid in the given context

Comment: Are you getting your list values from a excel or xlsm file?

Comment: From a localdb, Im using ef code first on a winform

Comment: Try adapt your code to that, I'm sorry if I'm not able to help you. This worked for me but as you are using a localdb I honestly don't know if this can give the help you need.