# How to map properties of inner/nested classes in DataGridView through BindingSource?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview, objectdatasource

I have a separate project for Data layer and there are two basic classes there:

```
[Serializable]
public class NesInfo
{
    public string FileName { get; private set; }
    public string Directory { get; private set; }
    public MapperInfo MapperInfo { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
[Serializable]
public class MapperInfo
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Prop1{ get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want my DataGridView to Display columns like this:
`[FileName][Directory][Number][Prop1][Prop2]`

How I can achieve this using BindingSource?

I've tried using my `BindingSource` in my DataGridView, but instead of 5 columns, I get 3 (the nested class is treated like one column, where the inner properties should be there instead):

[image]

And I cannot select the inner properties of MapperInfo class when trying to add columns: [image]

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130351/gridview-bound-with-properties-of-nested-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new class with all the properties that you want to be display in the grid and map it with your existing class either manually or using third-party libraries (ex. AutoMapper). Then bind the new class to Grid.

```
public class MyGridClass
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string Directory { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}

NesInfo ni = ...

MyGridClass gc = new MyGridClass ( );
gc.FileName = ni.FileName;
gc.Directory = ni.Directory;
gc.Number = ni.MapperInfo.Number;
gc.Prop1 = ni.MapperInfo.Prop1;
gc.Prop2 = ni.MapperInfo.Prop2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `CellFormatting` event handler. [DataGridView.CellFormatting Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender,
                                          DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.ColumnIndex < 0)
        return;
    DataGridViewColumn column = this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex];
    //For getting right column you can compare to the index
    //Or as in this example comparing to the names of the predefined columns
    if (column.Name.Equals(this.ColumnMapperInfoNumber.Name) == true)
    {
        MapperInfo temp = e.Value as MapperInfo;
        if (temp != null)
            e.Value = temp.Number;
    }
    else if(column.Name.Equals(this.ColumnMapperInfoProp1.Name) == true)
    {
        MapperInfo temp = e.Value as MapperInfo;
        if (temp != null)
            e.Value = temp.Prop1;  
    }
    else if(column.Name.Equals(this.ColumnMapperInfoProp2.Name) == true)
    {
        MapperInfo temp = e.Value as MapperInfo;
        if (temp != null)
            e.Value = temp.Prop2;
    }        
}
```

Another way which can be used is overriding `.ToString()` method in your class,
because `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` will execute this method on the bounded item for getting displayed text (that is why you see name of your class there).

```
[Serializable]
public class MapperInfo
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Prop1{ get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Number + ", " + this.Prop1 + ", " + this.Prop2;
    }
}
```

But I afraid this approach isn't for you, because you want different properties in the different columns

Answer (score 0):

Ended up creating a flat class used for grid view, and set up Mapping using [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started#how-do-i-use-automapper) from scratch:

```
private void Map(NesInfo ni,out RomInfoView romInfo)
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<NesInfo, RomInfoView>()
            .ForMember(x => x.MapperNumber, options => options.MapFrom(src => src.MapperInfo.Number))
            .ForMember(x => x.Prop1, options => options.MapFrom(src => src.MapperInfo.Prop1))
            .ForMember(x => x.Prop2,
                options => options.MapFrom(src => src.MapperInfo.Prop2));
        romInfo = Mapper.Map<RomInfoView>(ni);
    }
```

As suggested as @Vidhyardhi Gorrepati