# convert nested json to c# and bind to gridview

Tags: c#, json, gridview, nested

I am able to bind the top level json parameter but not the nested ones. What am I missing?
The nested one are completely ignored.

Code:

```cs
IEnumerable<coupaPO> empobj = null;
HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();
hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-API-KEY", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));//ACCEPT header
hc.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://company.com/api/");
var comsumeapi = hc.GetAsync("purchase_orders?id=1234");
comsumeapi.Wait();

var readdata = comsumeapi.Result;
if (readdata.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var displayrecords = readdata.Content.ReadAsAsync<IList<coupaPO>>();
    displayrecords.Wait();
    empobj = displayrecords.Result;
    GridView1.DataSource = empobj;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    // [...]
}
```

Classes: I have created classes for each json level and nested it with the class I'm binding to the gridview.

```cs
public partial class coupaPO
{
    [JsonProperty("po-number")]
    public string PONumber { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("created-at")]
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ship-to-attention")]
    public string ShipToAttention { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("erp-po-number")]
    public string erpponumber { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("buyer")]
    public Buyer Buyer { get; set; }
}

public partial class Buyer
{
    [JsonProperty("email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("fullname")]
    public string Fullname { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("custom-fields")]
    public CustomFields CustomFields { get; set; }
}

public partial class CustomFields
{
    [JsonProperty("po2go")]
    public string Po2Go { get; set; }
}
```

Manage to get this far
[image]

EDIT: I'm adding the JSON file. it is a portion of the one I receive from 3rd party vendor.

The Gridview columns are being auto-generated

```
 {
"id": 475652,
"created-at": "2020-03-04T15:12:20-05:00",
"po-number": "C000475652",
"ship-to-attention": "Kim Willis",
"coupa-accelerate-status": null,
"change-type": "revision",
"transmission-method-override": "supplier_default",
"transmission-emails": "",
"buyer": {
"id": 3104,
"email": "Azy.Lag@company.com",
"fullname": "Azy Lag",
"salesforce-id": null,
"avatar-thumb-url": null,
"buyer": "",
"el-self-approval": false,
"custom-fields": {
"po2go": ""
}
},
}
```

Comment: Would you share your JSON response with us too?

Comment: How did you define your `GridView`? Can you please show us? Did you use `AutoGenerateColumns`?

Comment: The gridview columns are auto-generated. yes

Comment: Then i think it will not work, `AutoGenerateColumns` considers only the properties of the object binded to it, and of course is not recursive.

Comment: Your problem is about showing nested properties, maybe this other Q&A could lead you to the solutio. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130351/gridview-bound-with-properties-of-nested-class)

Comment: Right on the money Federico Rossi. That article has the solution.